# wkhtmltopdf / phpwrapper do internal URL

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf and phpwrapper, all working great when using an external URL, however, I want to use it on a URL on the domain it is running on without doing an external call. The domain is ecure behind a login and the URL I am calling goes external when doing

```
addpage->
```

Can anybody please tell me how to get it working a URL on the domain I am running the function on - here is my code that works with an external URL

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;    

// Create a new Pdf object with some global PDF options
$pdf = new Pdf(array(
    'no-outline',         // Make Chrome not complain
    'no-background',         // Make Chrome not complain
    'margin-top'    => 20,
    'margin-right'  => 20,
    'margin-bottom' => 20,
    'margin-left'   => 20,

    // Default page options
    'disable-smart-shrinking',
    'user-style-sheet' => '/path/to/pdf.css',
));
```

This is the line that calls the URL that I need to work on the local domain this function is running on.

```
$pdf->addPage('https://google.com');
```

I want it to call a local URL without going external and getting a login page returned from the secure domain

```
    if (!$pdf->send()) {
        $error = $pdf->getError();
        // ... handle error here
    }    

?>
```

Comment: You need to be able to authorize without UI, something like OAuth token or similar.

Comment: `$pdf->addPage('http://localhost/path/to/page?<some-random-key>=<some-long-token-to-bypass-auth>');`

Comment: @Justinas why do I need to OAuth when it is on the same domain?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried this, but it goes external, is there a way to tell phpwrapper to stay local?

Comment: It does not matter same domain or not. It matter of authentication method - you need to authorize yourself from within code without user actions

Comment: Thanks for everybodys comments. I am going away to learn about OAuth...